# Can't find by _id in mongodb using nodejs driver 1.4

Tags: node-mongodb-native

I have a very basic app, that creates reports. I have a piece that is supposed to query and pull by _id from a mongo database. No matter what I cant get the find by _id to work. Mind you, just find() works when I need to show all reports. I've searched Overflow and tried a bunch of different solutions I have seen but none seem to work...:

```javascript
ObjectID(req.params.string)
new ObjectID(req.params.string)
BSON.ObjectID(req.params.id)
db.collection.serializer.ObjectID....etc
```

Here is the current code for the piece and I am using the newest versions of mongoDB and driver(2.6 and 1.4), thanks for any help guys!:
snippet from reportRoutes.js
    var mongo = require('mongodb');

```javascript
var Server = mongo.Server,
    Db = mongo.Db,
    BSON = mongo.BSONPure;
    ObjectID = mongo.ObjectID;

  exports.findById = function(req, res) {
  var id = new ObjectID.createFromHexString(req.params.id);
  console.log('Retrieving report: ' + id);
  db.collection('reports', function(err, collection) {
  db.collection.findOne({ '_id': (id)}, function(err, item) {
      res.send(item);
      });
  });
};
```

Snippet from Server.js

```javascript
    app.get('reports/:id', reportRoutes.findById);
```

Here is the console ouput when i goto

```javascript
http://localhost:3000/reports/53d2c100132358560c000001:
```

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCurrent' of undefined  popup.js:17

here is the mongo doc for when i goto

```javascript
http://localhost:3000/reports/ <-just does a collection.find()

{
"_id": "53d2c100132358560c000001",
"name": "Whatheheck",
"author": "cornhole",
"date": "07232014",
"costs": "200",
"cash": "2070",
"avoidances": "9000",
"reuse": "3000",
"recycle": "20000",
"time": "",
"description": "",
"picture": null
}
```

Here is the doc when pulled from the mongoshell using db.reports.find().pretty()

```javascript
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53d2c100132358560c000001"),
    "name" : "Whatheheck",
    "author" : "cornhole",
    "date" : "07232014",
    "costs" : "200",
    "cash" : "2070",
    "avoidances" : "9000",
    "reuse" : "3000",
    "recycle" : "20000",
    "time" : "",
    "description" : "",
    "picture" : null
}
```

Comment: Either of the first two will definitely work.  Can you update your question with the console.log output and a dump of the doc you're trying to find that shows its `_id`?

Comment: Hi Johnny, is that new info what you need? Thanks!

Comment: No, what does the doc look like when you query for it in the shell?

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  I wanted to make sure the `_id` in the doc was actually an ObjectID and not a string.

Answer (score 0):

In the `db.collection` callback, you're calling `db.collection.findOne` when you should be calling `collection.findOne`.  So something like this:

```js
exports.findById = function(req, res) {
    var id = ObjectID(req.params.id);
    db.collection('reports', function(err, collection) {
        collection.findOne({ '_id': id }, function(err, item) {
            res.send(item);
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks Johnny, i tried it but it still doesnt work. same error in the console log in chrome, and a 404 error in the nodejs console. Any other ideas on why it isn't working?

Comment: @SteveLiu If you're getting a 404 error, that means your route handler isn't even getting called and this doesn't have anything to do with MongoDB.  To be honest, you should really debug this rather than asking others to do that for you by looking for problems and guessing.

Comment: I'll double check the routeHandler, but the POST works for adding a report, and GET to get all reports work. I just can't get by single report...

Comment: @JohhnyHK I double checked everything and realized that instead of    app.get('reports/:id', reportRoutes.findById); it should of been pp.get('/reports/:id', reportRoutes.findById); Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 0):

This answer is most definitively beyond late for this inquiry, but I'm going to share my answer just in case somebody comes across this question since it is among the first results when you look it up:

Try checking the schema for the mongodb (or mongoose) model. If it has a property like:

```
_id: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
```

...just delete it. It will be handled automatically anyway and the String datatype is only interfering with ObjectId.

Answer (score -1):

@JohhnyHK I double checked everything and realized that instead of

```
app.get('reports/:id', reportRoutes.findById);
```

it should of been

```
app.get('/reports/:id', reportRoutes.findById);
```

Thanks for the pointer!